# Display Customers attribute to frontend in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am new to magento, I have created an attribute **language** from the magento back-end.
By following this. Customer > Attributes Manager

Attribute has an input type dropdown.

I want to show this on my front-end in phtml file to take input from the user.

How can i do this.

Thanks

Comment: i see only Manage Attributes under the catalog tab.Are you talking about that ? Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes

Comment: see Attributes Manager under the Customers drop down.
Customers->Attributes Manager->Customer's Attribute

Comment: on the fifth number.
Dashboad - Sales - Catalog - Mobile - **Customers** - Promotions .....

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'language'); //here, "language" is the attribute_code
$allOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true);
foreach ($allOptions as $instance) {
    $myArray[$instance['value']] = $instance['label'];
}
print_r(($myArray));
```

Comment: no, its not working. i also replace my attribute_code.
Actually its not a product attribute code.
its Customers attribute under the **Customers** tab

Comment: Then sorry i haven't the extension and no information.you can connect the support team of them for this issue.

Comment: what is **catalog_product** in the first line of above code in getAttribute method

Comment: It is magento Model class for products.

Comment: Thanks Mahmood. U saved me.

Comment: Tried using this for customer model and it worked like a charm thanks @MahmoodRehman
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'language'); //here, "language" is the attribute_code
$allOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true);
foreach ($allOptions as $instance) {
    $myArray[$instance['value']] = $instance['label'];
}